# Cross-Origin Read Blocking on React app but not Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, fetch, cross-origin-read-blocking

Migrating to React frontend from legacy Laravel app. Using Fetch to call an API. It works on laravel (using fopen and stream_get_contents to get data) so I know it is not a server issue as using same localhost. But for React, using fetch to grab data from api but get this error:
[image]

I have changed the Content Type to be application/json to match header but still nothing. My response body is empty. When I go to the API link, I get an xml file so the link works and I can see it on my browser but my react app is not holding the response body information.

```
   apiCall = () => {
    const exampleAPILink = 'My_API_URL'
    const config = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
   };
fetch(exampleAPILink, config).then(function(response){
  console.log(response.body);
  //null
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

}

*I need the 'no-cors' or will get CORS forbidden access error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no-cors` means you are telling fetch that you do not intend to do anything that requires CORS permission and that it should not ask for it.

The problem is that you *are* doing something that requires CORS permission. You are are trying to read a cross-origin response.

The CORBs error is the result.

You need to change the mode to `cors` and change the server you are requesting the data from so it grants permission.

---

You are making a GET request. It makes no sense to set a `Content-Type` header on it. There is no request body to describe the type of.

You might be confusing `Content-Type` with `Accept`.

`application/json` is not a simple Content-Type, so you not only require CORS permission to read the response, but the browser will send a preflight request to ask permission to sent the request in the first place.

Don't set a `Content-Type` header on a GET request.

Comment: @AndreGomes — Then you can't make Ajax requests directly to their server.